# Deal With NaN values in dataset for key-point coordinate detection

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, nan

I am creating a key-point detection deep learning algorithm in Python (using pandas for data, and keras/tensorflow) to detect anatomic landmarks in an image. For example, the input would be an image (say the face) and the output would be the pixel coordinates (x,y) of the center of each of the eyes in the image. The problem I am facing is that I have multiple anatomic landmarks I'm looking for (eyes, nose, mouth, etc.) but these are not always in the input image which leads to NaN values for certain (x,y) coordinates. I would like to keep the NaN values so that the algorithm will know when those features are in the image, and when they are not. I don't want to change the NaN values to 0 either because that will affect another process down the line that I am using the key-point algorithm for. Is there a way to keep the NaN values but still train the algorithm? Attached is a basic layout of the data I am using.([Pixel coordinate data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvfah.png))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you want your model to predict when the landmark is not visible in the image?
What does your downstream task expect in that case?

One possible option for you is to output *three* numbers per landmark: its `x` and `y` coordinates (as you are doing now) and an additional binary variable `v` that is 1 if the landmark is visible and zero otherwise.

In that case, during training, you should provide 3 targets per landmark: `gt_x`, `gt_y` and `gt_v`. For visible points (those without `NaN`s in your set) `gt_v` should be 1, whereas for the invisible points (those with `NaN`s) `gt_v` should be 0 and you can plug any number to `gt_x` and `gt_y` for these points.

You should have two loss functions: the first is a [binary cross-entropy loss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss.html#torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss) between the predicted visibility and the true visibility `gt_v` of each point.
The second loss is a regression loss between the predicted `x, y` coordinates and the targets. **But** (and this is crucial) you only compute the second loss for points that their `gt_v == 1`!

In test time, you should check the predicted visibility of the landmarks `pred_v`, and consider only landmarks for which the model predicted they are visible.

Comment: The goal would be that if the landmark is not in the image, then the model would not predict that landmark (just leave it blank) while predicting the other visible landmarks. The downstream task is to calculate the middle of the landmark locations (median of the coordinates) which is why I want to avoid using 0 for NaN values as that would affect calculation. That sounds like a great idea with the 3 targets per landmark, thank you! How would I implement in code the two loss functions at the same time? Or would it be better to have two separate networks, one for landmarks, one for coordinates?

Comment: @cloud77 same network, two "heads", two loss functions where the overall loss is weighted sum of the two.

Comment: Gotcha, okay. That's something I've never done before so I'll have to look into how to implement it in code. Thank you again!